# Does 'noun + there is' mean 'existing + noun'?

Tags: meaning

In the sentence, does ***the hardest work (that) there is*** mean ***the hardest, existing work***? Or are there any other interpretations?

> Most parents think that if our child would just “behave,” we could
> maintain composure as parents. The truth is that managing our own
> emotions and actions is what allows us to feel peaceful as parents.
> Ultimately we can’t control our children or the obstacles they will
> face ― but we can always control our own actions. Parenting isn’t
> about what our child does, but about how we respond. In fact, most of
> what we call parenting doesn’t take place between a parent and child
> but within the parent. When a storm brews, a parent’s response will
> either calm it or trigger a full‐scale tsunami. Staying calm enough to
> respond constructively to all that childish behavior ― and the stormy
> emotions behind it ― requires that we grow, too. If we can use those
> times when our buttons get pushed to reflect, not just react, we can
> notice when we lose equilibrium and steer ourselves back on track.
> This inner growth is ***the hardest work there is***, but it’s what enables
> you to become a more peaceful parent, one day at a time.

[Peaceful Parent, Happy Kids: How to Stop Yelling and Start Connecting](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=EYQyoR-oqqAC&pg=PR20&lpg=PR20&dq=If%20we%20can%20use%20those%20times%20when%20our%20buttons%20get%20pushed%20to%20reflect,%20not%20just%20react,%20we%20can%20notice%20when%20we%20lose%20equilibrium%20and%20steer%20ourselves%20back%20on%20track.%20This%20inner%20growth%20is%20the%20hardest%20work%20there%20is,%20but%20it%E2%80%99s%20what%20enables%20you%20to%20become%20a%20more%20peaceful%20parent,%20one%20day%20at%20a%20time.&source=bl&ots=vGqTnzWLiI&sig=ACfU3U0m32LmmYSw0XWVjhXvGLHE8X2rWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgp-bs59_-AhWOmlYBHQJaDTMQ6AF6BAggEAM#v=onepage&q=If%20we%20can%20use%20those%20times%20when%20our%20buttons%20get%20pushed%20to%20reflect%2C%20not%20just%20react%2C%20we%20can%20notice%20when%20we%20lose%20equilibrium%20and%20steer%20ourselves%20back%20on%20track.%20This%20inner%20growth%20is%20the%20hardest%20work%20there%20is%2C%20but%20it%E2%80%99s%20what%20enables%20you%20to%20become%20a%20more%20peaceful%20parent%2C%20one%20day%20at%20a%20time.&f=false)

Comment: Why do you question whether the "hardest work" is "existing"? Are you suggesting that it might refer to work that doesn't exist?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It's possible the OP's native language has two different verbs for copula and existence, where English uses "be" for both, and they want to know how to understand "is" in this sentence.

Comment: Otherwise, does it mean the hardest work 'indeed'? Please, tell me what 'there is' means in the sentence.

Comment: Yes, it does mean _the hardest work that exists_.

Comment: @gotube Yes, I agree. I was just hoping that we could get some more detail about what OP thought the "other interpretations" might be.

Comment: *The [hardest work, biggest thing, oldest man,...] there **is*** means the "most extreme" version ***currently in existence***. Not necessarily the same thing as *The [most extreme version] there **could be.*** This is just the basic difference between ***is*** and ***could be***, but in practice it's a meaningless distinction in OP's exact cited context.

Comment: The sentence, “*X* is the hardest work **there is**,” is equivalent in meaning to, “**There is** no work harder than *X*.” Its form is completely analogous to that of “*X* is the hardest work he’s ever done.”